# AutoMagically Insert Password With Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to automate my ancible deployment just trying to learn more about it, I'm trying to automagically insert the password for the machine when copying the ssh key however It still prompts me for the password everytime and I'm not sure why, maybe its sending the keys before the prompt I'm not sure..

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update --force-yes
apt-get install software-properties-common -y --force-yes
apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible -y --force-yes
apt-get update -y --force-yes
apt-get install ansible -y --force-yes
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
ssh-copy-id root@0.0.0.0
send("mypass{enter}")
```

Comment: `send` is an `expect` command not a shell command. You cannot just use `send` like that.

Comment: @EtanReisner Then how would you suggest I do it ?

Comment: If you want to use `expect` then you use expect. If you don't you set up ssh keys. If you can't/don't want to do that you could also look into `sshpass` But keys is the best approach.

Comment: how would I use expect?

Comment: Oz123's answer is a reasonable example of an expect script for that purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use expect, or if you know python, you can use the simple module Pexpect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

set ip [lindex $argv 0]

set user [lindex $argv 1]

set password [lindex $argv 2]

spawn ssh "$user\@$ip"

expect "Password:"

send "$password\r";

interact
```

But **your best option is to configure your server to allow ssh with key authentication.**

Comment: Perl also has a module for expect...http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid putting your password in any type of script if you can help it -- and you can. `ssh`, `rsync`, etc.. are all capabale of remote operation by **public-key/private-key** authentication. Use it. Unless you have some need for **rsa** encryption, use **dsa**.

How? You are on the right track. Let's say you are on `localhost` and want to update/manage `remotehost`. What do the ansible docs say?

> When speaking with remote machines, Ansible by 
>   default assumes you are using SSH keys.

**How to setup SSH keys?**

Simple. You need to generate your **public/private** keypair on `localhost` and you will then transfer the **public-key** to `remotehost` and append it to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Generating the keypair is a single command (default length is fine):

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

Which by default will create the following on `localhost` in `~/.ssh/`:

```
-rw------- 1 youruser yourgroup 668 Jun 13  2008 id_dsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 youruser yourgroup 603 Jun 13  2008 id_dsa.pub
```

**Note:** the permissions must be `0600` on your **private-key** `id_dsa`.

**Transfering public-key to `remotehost`**

```
rsync -uav ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub remotehost:~/.ssh/id_dsa-localhost.pub
```

**Note:** just by convention, it is a good idea to give the **public-key** a unique name on `remotehost` to avoid inadvertently overwriting a public-key from another host. (i.e. - transfer `id_dsa.pub` as `id_dsa-localhost.pub`) Now all you need to do is append the public-key to the `authorized_keys` file:

```
ssh remotehost "cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa-localhost.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Now login from `localhost` to `remotehost` **securely** using your private-key:

```
ssh remotehost
```

That's all there is to it.

**I need to transfer files as `root`, now what**

Beyond all the normal cautionary tails about not doing it, etc..., you have 2 options: either create another public/private keypair for root; or, if you are the only admin/user and this is your box, then simply `su` to `root` and copy your `/home/you/.ssh/id_dsa` and `/home/you/.ssh/id_dsa.pub` to `/root/.ssh` on `localhost`.

Then on `remotehost` (again, your box), `copy` `/home/you/.ssh/id_dsa-localhost.pub` to `/root/.ssh/id_dsa-localhost.pub` and then append `/root/.ssh/id_dsa-localhost.pub` to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` (you must **check/update** the `owner:group` of all files copied to `root:root` and insure the permissions are correct.)

**Note:** while the `sshd` default allows `root` login, some distributions don't. You must insure that `PermitRootLogin` is not set to `No` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

That should be it. If there are any issues, attempt `ssh` login with `ssh -vv` and you will get all the information needed to diagnose the issue.